# Consulta SQL en MYSQL que me agrupe los datos por segmento de tiempo

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta SQL en donde me agrupe el resultado en segmentos de tiempo, es decir que me calcule el promedio de un dato cada 5 min, mi consulta por ahora va asi:

```
SELECT DATE AS DATE, method AS METHOD, red AS red, state AS STATE
FROM table
WHERE STATE = 155
GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: que te muestra hasta hora? pon ejemplos de lo que muestra, de lo que esperas y de la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: Me muestra los registros que con state = 155